# URL not decoded correctly using Decodable Swift 4 protocol

Tags: ios, url, swift4, codable, decodable

I receive this url string from the server:

```
{
   "image":"http:\/\/site.se\/wp-content\/uploads\/2012\/09\/Hidl\u00f8gsma.jpg"
}
```

the value is:

`http://site.se/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Hidløgsma.jpg`

Using the Swift 4 Decodable protocol fails with error:

> Invalid URL string.

is there a way to make it work with the above string ?

Comment: Did you tried with let urlStrin = strUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed)

Comment: @TofaaniKaanudo it works but then I need to implement `init` method my self , I am now just adding the `Decodable` conformance  to the object

Comment: Can your server transfer non-ascii data percent encoded?

Comment: @user28434 which encoding will be passed for an URL ?

Comment: If I remember correctly, in Swift 4 only UTF8 percent encoding works.